# Null.Pointer.Exception in my web app

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a web app that is querying my oracle database and returns a list of menu titles from a table but when i navigate to the page it throws the area shown below.

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
oracle.DatabaseConnector.selectAllMenus(DatabaseConnector.java:63)
org.apache.jsp.menus_jsp._jspService(menus_jsp.java:113)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.
```

Below is the offending part of the code inside my java class that queries the database. But i am not sure why this would cause the above error? Can someone take a look and see if there is a problem?

```
public MenuList selectAllMenus(String ordering) {
    MenuList list = null;

    try {
        String strQuery = "SELECT title"
                + " FROM menus"
                + " ORDER BY " + ordering;
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);

        results = stmt.executeQuery();

        list = new MenuList(results);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}
```

This is what was in the log file:

```
28-Feb-2012 14:40:57 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.DatabaseConnector.selectAllMenus(DatabaseConnector.java:63)
at org.apache.jsp.menus_jsp._jspService(menus_jsp.java:113)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: which line is exactly at the `DatabaseConnector.java:63`?

Comment: The line in question is    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);

Comment: Ahh.. then as @vulkanio said, it must be your `conn` which is null at this point. Also as he said, put a catch block for `Exception e` and do a `e.printStackTrace()` Would help to understand the error more correctly.

Comment: I'd suggest to go through a bit decent JDBC tutorial. The way how you're managing DB resources is wrong.

Comment: Also add `results.close();` and `stmt.close()` and `ResultSet results = ...;`. @BalusC meant it well. Ensure that the MenuList constructor copies the values immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in your logs : `Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs`

But the error message itself is pretty clear : The db connection is null, probably your connection string/parameters are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are using MySQL DB..

Make sure you add the correct MySQL Java Connector as an external library and also add Tomcat as an external server (In the Build Path of the Project in Eclipse).

(You can also copy all the libraries in the lib folder of your $TOMCAT_HOME/$CATALINA_HOME to your build path.

This should resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**I assume `conn` is open.**

Instead of printing the stack trace, why don't you print the error message?

Comment: `printStackTrace` does include the message. System-generated `NullPointerException`s do not have messages — the first stack trace line number is your source of information.

Answer (score 0):

line:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);
```

"conn" is not being created in any place

try something like this to create a connection:

```
public class MyConnection {
Connection conn;
String username;
String password;
public Connection getConnection(){
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourDBName?";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        try {
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return conn;
}

}
```